# JFace ComboViewer with a header entry?

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, jface

I'm interested in populating a ComboViewer with a list of objects.
I know JFace has some nice features that support that, but what if I want to make the first entry in the ComboViewer something like 
`<Select Connection>`
or some other dummy entry that doesn't have an object associated to it? Is there any simple generic solution to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with the [TableCombo](http://www.eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/tablecombo/tablecombo.php) widget from the Nebula project. You can a create TableComboViewer with input, selection listeners etc. but also set the text of the combo independently from the current selection.

```
TableComboViewer viewer = ...
...
viewer.getTableCombo().setText("...");
```

I use this in a current project. However the TableCombo is in alpha state, but in my application it works quite fine.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can't do it out of the box. You can write you own LabelProvider to do this, or you may want to switch to something like a ListViewer in a popup window, and use the List's headers to display your special first element.